# Scanning character and integer in single scanf multiple times

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
int a,i;
 char b;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 scanf("%c %d",&a,&b);
```

}

The program only scans twice (each for char and int) and then terminates.

**OUTPUT**

r

3

4

t

Now program is terminating rather than scanning two more times(one char and one int)

Comment: don't see any print statements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf(" %c %d",&a,&b);
```

solves the problem

Answer (score -3):

The program scan twice because you tell him to with `i < 3`.
Change the 3 to 5 to scan 4 times.

Comment: It scans 3 times only for i<5 i.e. 3 times for a and 3 for b